# Framework GoColly - Redirect to HTTPS doesn't work

Tags: go

I am using the framework GoColly to get the body of some urls. Right now I am testing the Netflix website and I have this code below

```
u = "http://netflix.com"
uri, err := url.Parse(u)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    continue
}

c := colly.NewCollector()
c.AllowedDomains = []string{"netflix.com"}

c.OnResponse(func(r *colly.Response) {
    q.r.Set("success:"+u, string(r.Body))
})
c.OnError(func(r *colly.Response, err error) {
    log.Println(err.Error())
    q.r.Set("failed:"+u, err.Error())
})

c.Visit(uri.String())
c.Wait()
```

and when I execute it retuns this error ***Get https://www.netflix.com/: Not following redirect to www.netflix.com because its not in AllowedDomains***

any thoughts?

Comment: Have you confirmed the problem is actually redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS, or possibly that it's redirecting to `https://www.netflix.com` (notice the www.)? That seems like what the error is suggesting is the issue. In the context of this library, a subdomain (www) may not be considered a part of the larger domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you specified domain here `c.AllowedDomains = []string{"netflix.com"}` without `www`  subdomain, thats the resone it's not found within allowed domains.

```
c.AllowedDomains = []string{"www.netflix.com"}
```